# TWebbrowser can't render specific page correctly (Delphi 11)

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser

I'm trying to display the page http://ekloges-prev.singularlogic.eu/2019/v/home/municipaldistricts/814/ in `TWebBrowser` but I get the error:

> unable to get property 'remove' of undefined or null reference

But the page `http://ekloges-prev.singularlogic.eu/v2012b/public/index.html#{%22cls%22:%22level%22,%22params%22:{%22level%22:%22ep%22, %22id%22:36}}` displays as expected. Both pages contain JavaScript and both open normally in Chrome, but it looks like the first page requires some extra setup in `TWebBrowser` to render properly. Here is an application to demonstrate the problem:

```
unit Unit5;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.OleCtrls, SHDocVw, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form5: TForm5;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // not shown correctly, same with .Navigate2()
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://ekloges-prev.singularlogic.eu/2019/v/home/municipaldistricts/814/');

  // this one shows correctly
  //WebBrowser1.Navigate('http://ekloges-prev.singularlogic.eu/v2012b/public/index.html#{%22cls%22:%22level%22,%22params%22:{%22level%22:%22ep%22,%22id%22:36}}');
end;

end.
```

Comment: [TWebBrowser](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser) relies on an old `IWebBrowser2` interface which means that web pages are actually opened in Internet Explorer instance. IE does not support many of newer web features.. You should instead use [TEdgeBrowser](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Edge.TEdgeBrowser) which is using Chromium at its core. You can read more on how to use it at [Using TEdgeBrowser Component](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_TEdgeBrowser_Component_and_Changes_to_the_TWebBrowser_Component)

Comment: I had tried `TEdgeBrowser` before following the instructions on the page `Using TEdgeBrowser Component` but, like today, I had not been able to display any pages. TEdgeBrowser behaves as if it doesn't exist. I have `Win 10/64bit`, `Edge 113.0.1774.42 (official build, 64 bit)` and I am creating an application for `win32`. I downloaded the `1.0.1774.30 package` and copied the build\x64\WebView2Loader.dll inside the folder where the exe file is created. I also tried with build\x86\WebView2Loader.dll but still the browser doesn't do anything. Can you please help me further? I am desperate

Comment: @JimPapas I just tried those web pages with WebView4Delphi and CEF4Delphi browsers and they work fine. That means that TEdgeBrowser should also work.

Comment: @SalvadorDíazFau, 
Does it then need some other setting in my system, apart from the ones I mentioned, for it to work?

Comment: @JimPapas : Install WebView2 runtime. Use the evergreen standalone installer from here : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/#download-section . After that, build your application and make sure WebView2Loader.dll is in the same directory as the EXE of your application.

Comment: @SalvadorDíazFau. Thanks, CEF4Delphi works with my pages. Trying to install the evergreen installer (x86 or x64) the system responds that is already installed but TEdgeBrowser dos not show any pages. If I use your miniBrowser it opens the pages but I need to read the final HTML code (after jsScript execution). How can achiεve this, please ?

Comment: @JimPapas : If you decide to use CEF4Delphi then call TChromium.RetrieveHTML and use the TChromium.OnTextResultAvailable event to receive the HTML contents. Notice that TChromium.RetrieveHTML has a "aFrameName" parameter because you can only get the HTML contents from one frame at a time. MiniBrowser implements all this in the context menu. See the TMiniBrowserFrm.CopyHTMLMsg and TMiniBrowserFrm.Chromium1TextResultAvailable procedures.

Comment: @SalvadorDíazFau. I tried the miniBrowser and I was able to retrieve the HTML as I wanted. Can I do the same with tinyBrowser ? because I only want to retrieve the HTML not actually display the page so I want the minimum code for this. Is it possible, please ?

Comment: @JimPapas TinyBrowser uses a much different browser configuration. If you just want the HTML without showing anything then try the WebpageSnapshot demo. That demo loads a webpage in a hidden browser to take a snapshot but you can modify the TCEFBrowserThread.WebpagePostProcessing procedure to call RetrieveHTML. Use the OnTextResultAvailable event to trigger a new event that will be used to copy the HTML from the main thread.

Comment: @SalvadorDíazFau, many thanks for your help. `WebpageSnapshot` seems more close to my goal but I can't find the `FThread.WebpagePostProcessing` procedure nor `RetrieveHTML` or `OnTextResultAvailable`. Where are they ?

Comment: @JimPapas : Please download the latest CEF4Delphi source code from GitHub. I added a feature in the WebpageSnapshot demo for VCL to copy the HTML.